# Android listview using json data from a url

Tags: android

I need help creating a listview from json data from a url in android. Are there any easy and good tutorials available using android studio?

Comment: Have you searched before asking???

Comment: This question is too generic. Search 1) how to make a server call 2) how to parse JSON 3) how to create a custom adapter for listview

Comment: i tried searching but the tutorials are old. they use eclipse instead of android studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can learn it from here.

- [Parse JSON data from a web server and display on ListView](http://javatechig.com/android/android-networking-tutorial)

Comment: use `HttpUrlConnection` in your app